# Javascript hide/show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show, hidden

I have a javascript hide/show div with 4 different divs going. It is working partially but not performing the way I would like. When I click one of the divs it opens up the hidden div, which is perfect, but when I click the other link to open up the other div I want the other one I clicked first to close and then the new one to open. Here is my javascript.

```
$('[id^="hideshow"]').on('click', function(event) {
    var dataValue = $(this).attr('data-value');
    dataValue = $('#'+dataValue);
    $(dataValue).toggle('hide');
});

<a class="pure-button pure-button-primary" type='button' id='hideshow1' value='hide/show' data-value="content1"><div class="witb">
    <hr class="dark2">
  <p></p>Whats in the Bag &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:24px"></i></p>
  </div>
</div></a>

    <div id='content2' style="display:none">
<div class="wedge-thumbs">
  <img class="thumbs" src="build/wedge-thumb.png?$staticlink$" alt="Milled Grind Header">
  <a href="#" class="customize"><span style="customize"> Customize It</span></a>
  <hr class="dark">
  <span class="title">Milled Grind 54&deg; LB</span>

</div>
<div class="wedge-thumbs">
  <img class="thumbs" src="build/wedge-thumb.png?$staticlink$" alt="Milled Grind Header">
  <a href="#" class="customize"><span style="customize"> Customize It</span></a>
  <hr class="dark">
  <span class="title">Milled Grind 54&deg; LB</span>

</div>

<div class="wedge-thumbs">
  <img class="thumbs" src="build/wedge-thumb.png?$staticlink$" alt="Milled Grind Header">
  <a href="#" class="customize"><span style="customize"> Customize It</span></a>
  <hr class="dark">
  <span class="title">Milled Grind 54&deg; LB</span>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Provide your html.

Comment: Seems like it's improper because nothing is visible.

Comment: `style="display:none"` ... aaand where are your buttons?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan oops. I edited my code

Comment: your HTML markup is messed up....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Hopefully you have some selector reference to target them all
var $all = $(".drops");  // Clearly I used .drops for example

$('[data-value]').on('click', function(event) {

    var $target = $('#'+ this.dataset.value);

    $all.not( $target ).hide(); // Hide all but target one
    $target.toggle();           // Toggle target one
});
```

Here's an improved example:

```js
var $all = $(".togglable");

$('[data-toggle]').on('click', function(event) {

  var $target = $(this.dataset.toggle);

  $all.not( $target ).hide(); // Hide all but target one
  $target.toggle();           // Toggle target one
});
```

```css
[data-toggle]{cursor:pointer; display:inline-block; color:#0bf; padding:0 8px;}
.hidden{display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a data-toggle="#el1">TOGGLE1</a>
<a data-toggle="#el2">TOGGLE2</a>
<a data-toggle="#el3">TOGGLE3</a>

<div id="el1" class="togglable hidden">ELEMENT1</div>
<div id="el2" class="togglable hidden">ELEMENT2</div>
<div id="el3" class="togglable hidden">ELEMENT3</div>
```

Comment: Seems like this is on track of what I am trying to achieve. So now when I open the hidden div then click the other button to open the other hidden div it closes the 1st div but does not open the 2nd div. I want it to open the 2nd div when the other one is open.

Comment: @sizemattic added an example. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes almost there! How do I make it so all the divs are all hidden when the page loads? @Roko C. Buljan

Comment: @sizemattic well... probably just like I did. Adding a class `.hidden` could help.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
$('[id^="hideshow"]').on('click', function(event) {
var dataValue = $(this).attr('data-value');
dataValue = $('#'+dataValue);
$(dataValue).toggleClass('hide');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It will be better if you could give your divs a common class instead of ids so you could hide other divs using this common class like :

```
$('.common_class').addClass('hide');
```

If you cant you could loop through all the divs and hide them before showing the current clicked one :

```
$('[id^="hideshow"]').on('click', function(event) {
    $('[id^="hideshow"]').each(function(){
        $('#'+$(this).data('value')).addClass('hide');
    });

    dataValue_id = $('#'+$(this).data('value'));
    $(dataValue_id).toggleClass('hide');
});
```

Hope this helps.

**Snippet using common classes :**

```js
$('.common_class').on('click', function(event) {
    $('.common_class_2').not($('.common_class_2', this)).addClass('hide');
    $('.common_class_2', this).toggleClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.hide{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='common_class'>DIV 1
  <p class='common_class_2'>Content 1</p>
</div>
<div class='common_class'>DIV 2
  <p class='common_class_2 hide'>Content 2</p>
</div>
<div class='common_class'>DIV 3
  <p class='common_class_2 hide'>Content 3</p>
</div>
<div class='common_class'>DIV 4
  <p class='common_class_2 hide'>Content 4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: How would I make it so that so when you click the div it closes it again? I don't want to one to be open all the time.

Comment: @sizemattic is that not what you're looking for ?